# Fetch All Value

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have this code:

```
$query_search_select = $db->prepare("SELECT * , COUNT(*) AS coun FROM users WHERE user LIKE :keyword ;");
$query_search_select->bindParam(":keyword" , $key_search , PDO::PARAM_STR ) ;
$query_search_select->execute();
```

The query works, but when i take the information as this:

```
while($res = $query_search_select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
// code 
}
```

But the loop during only 1 time, in COUNT(*) result 2 (it is right) but this loop during only 1 time... why? I search on stackoverflow and internet, i've tried fetchAll but with it i've the same problem...

Comment: why dont you use `fetchAll` ?

Comment: your echo'ed row should contain something like `$res['coun'];` as per `AS coun` or remove `, COUNT(*) AS coun` if you're not going to be using it in your echo; which is not shown in your question, so we don't know how you're using this.

Comment: yes i agree with @Fred-ii-, your `while` sample is not giving much information how you display/return the results. May you just override your result all the time...

Comment: the problem is : `$res_search = $query_search_select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`have only one result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is, that `COUNT()` is a `GROUP BY` or aggregate function 
(see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

so if you are using `COUNT()` in your `MySQL` statement, your resultset is automatically grouped to one row.

but you still can do it like this:

```
"SELECT * , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user LIKE :keyword) AS coun FROM users WHERE user LIKE :keyword2"
```

**NOTE:**
you'll have to add another parameter binding since parameters can only be used once in the `MySQL` statement:

```
$query_search_select->bindParam(":keyword2" , $key_search , PDO::PARAM_STR ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$result = $query_search_select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($result);
```

**Note:** you dont have to use a `while` with `fetchAll`

In your case you should see if all info is in the result

```
while($res = $query_search_select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $collection[] = $res;
}
print_r($collection);
```

But as shown above, this could be handled in 1 row :)

**Note 2:** Your count in your select statement is kind of useless. Actually you have affected rows and you can get these with `$query_search_select->rowCount();`

**Note 3:**

### I guess this is your main problem.

Check your `LIKE` statement. You have no `%` in there. If you have **foo** and **foobar** in your db and use your statment like you build it searching for **foo**, you will only 
get 1 result returned!!! The `LIKE`statement looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE name LIKE '%foo%'
```

Returns entrys with name `foo` and the entry **can have values before and after foo**

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE name LIKE '%foo'
```

Returns entrys with name `foo` and the entry **can have values before foo**

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE name LIKE 'foo%'
```

Returns entrys with name `foo` and the entry **can have values after foo**

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE name LIKE 'foo'
```

Returns entrys with name `foo` and the entry **CAN'T** have values after or before foo

Comment: i've try with fetchall, but with print r 've only one result

Comment: @Carbos can you provide my with a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and some sample data ?

Comment: @Carbos see my changes in my post

Comment: the problem was with count(*)

Answer (score 0):

Second time I've responded to this question today. Don't use `fetchAll()` in a loop. It returns an array. If you need to look up PHP arrays in order to understand what this means, I suggest that course of action.

Then loop over the returned array, instead of trying to loop over the results of iterated `fetch()`.